# Connecting WFS/OGC API - Features(GeoServer) in QGIS using Python

Tags: python, wfs, ogr, ogc-api-features

I made feature count program but it works when shapefile is saved. I want to make the program that connect to server and count features.

I made codes that count features which is saved.

```py
from osgeo import ogr
import os

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
variable = 'path'
dataSource1 = driver.Open(variable, 0)
layer1 = dataSource1.GetLayer()
featureCount1 = layer1.GetFeatureCount()
print("variable = ", featureCount,"개")
```

How can I modify the code and connect to GeoServer and count features?

Comment: It is certainly possible to modify your code and use another driver and get another layer but notice also that OGC API Features does not have any query for fast feature count. It means that GDAL must download the whole collection before it can tell the number of features.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works